# How can I modify this animated gradient script to have a constant opacity of 70%?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to modify the following script: http://codepen.io/quasimondo/pen/lzpBI.

My goal is to make the gradient to have an opacity of .7 or 70% at all times, so that I can use it as an overlay. I am aware that I can change the opacity of the div with css, but Id like to learn how its done with javascript. I have tried modifying this line:

```
var alphaValues = [1,1,1,1];
```

to

```
var alphaValues = [.7,.7,.7,.7];
```

Which seems to give some kind of result, but the transparency is still not constant, and seems to increase back to 100% some of the time.

Comment: http://codepen.io/adeneo/pen/ozGjaL

Comment: Neat, thank you! Any chance you could explain how this works? I am trying to better understand javascript.

Comment: I just harcoded in 0.7 in the RGBA values ?